# Installing recen version of GCC

Tags: g++, g++4.8

I am a novice so please bear with me if I ask something that is silly in nature. I wanted to install getfem++ on my Mac for my research and had to compile it from the source as per the instructions given at:

http://download.gna.org/getfem/html/homepage/python/install.html#in-a-general-unix-linux-based-systems

However, when I give the following command:

```
./configure --enable-python=yes
```

it gives me the following error:

```
configure: error: g++ do not support option -std=c++11. Update g++ to at least release 4.8.1.
```

SO I installed g++ using Homebrew and as per the instructions given by @quine on

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler

I edited the bash profile and added the necessary lines to set alias.

Then I checked the g++ version using `g++ -v` 
and it says 4.8.5 as per the last line. Now when I run the configure command as before, I get the same error. as: `configure: error: g++ do not support option -std=c++11. Update g++ to at least release 4.8.1.`

Can someone help me by pointing out where I am going wrong? Thank you!!

Comment: Could it be, that you have two g++ installed? Maybe the one the installer finds is old and the one you use when doing a g++ -v is new?

Comment: well.. that could be one of the reasons as you correctly pointed out @doh-nutz. But I edited the bash_profile to include all aliases of g++/c++ pointing to the latest version. I think that should be taken care of.